# Is it possible to restrict the root element to a type derived from a specified parent type?

Tags: xml, xsd

Let's start with a simple schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="AnimalType" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="legs" xml:base="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="DogType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="AnimalType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="furColor" xml:base="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="BirdType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="AnimalType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="canFly" xml:base="xs:boolean"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Is it possible to define a root `xs:element` named `pet` that can be of any animal type? I.e. to make both of those documents valid:

```
<!-- a dog -->
<pet>
    <legs>4</legs>
    <furColor>black</furColor>
</pet>


<!-- a bird -->
<pet>
    <legs>2</legs>
    <canFly>true</canFly>
</pet>
```

Adding `<xs:element name="pet" type="AnimalType"/>` does not work, because `AnimalType` is abstract (and even if it wasn't I still wouldn't be able to add child elements from a derived type).

I need the `pet` to be an instance of the `AnimalType`, so setting the `pet`'s type to `xs:anyType` is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and the fact that a comment is needed to differentiate the two `pet` cases should be taken as a signal that the XML design goal should be questioned here rather than the capabilities of XSD.

Here are a couple alternative XML designs:

1. A document can have different root node possibilities, so simply
   permit both `dog` and `bird` root elements, with their respective
   types both derived from a common `AnimalType`.
2. XSD 1.1 supports [Conditional Type Assignment (CTA)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative), so add an attribute to
   `AnimalType` that could be tested to differentiate the `DogType` and
   `BirdType` alternative possibilities of a `pet` root element.  You can find an [example of CTA here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878402/how-to-make-type-depend-on-attribute-value-using-conditional-type-assignment).

I would favor #1.

Comment: #1 would be the best, I agree. However, in this special case I'm limited by some legacy code and old protocols. #2 will solve my problems.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to explicitely assign the type of the element thanks to `xsi:type`.

In the case of the dog, you can use (assuming your schema has been save in animals.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="animals.xsd" xsi:type="DogType">
    <legs>4</legs>
    <furColor>red</furColor>
</pet>
```

And for the bird:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="animals.xsd" xsi:type="BirdType">
    <legs>2</legs>
    <canFly>true</canFly>
</pet>
```