# XSD for element whose type depends on an attribute value?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, schema

I am trying to create an XSD for the following XML file:

```
<config xmlns="tbd">
    <root>C:\workspace\</root>
    <zone type="directories" delay="30000">
        <directory>output</directory>
        <directory>input</directory>
        <directory>errors</directory>
    </zone>
    <zone type="database" delay="50000">
        <table name="OUTPUT_VIEW">
            <column>ID</column>
            <column>TYPE</column>
            <column>SUB_TYPE</column>
            <column>COUNT(*)</column>
            <column>SUM(BASE_AMOUNT)</column>
        </table>
    </zone>
</config>
```

I am having problems creating the XSD for this as the `zone` element can be of two types as per the XML file.

Answer (score 2):

### XSD 1.0

You cannot have the content model vary per the value of an attribute in XSD 1.0.  If you can redesign the XML, then consider splitting `zone` to be two different elements,  `directories` or `database`.  If you cannot redesign the XML, then you can merge the separate content models and make all elements not shared by both models be optional; you'll lose the ability to enforce some requiredness requirements, but at least you'll be able to cover both cases.

### XSD 1.1

This is exactly what [**Conditional Type Assignment**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative) is designed to do.  See [*How to make type depend on attribute value using Conditional Type Assignment*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27878402/290085) for an example.