# XSD validation of list items based on type attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Suppose I have this XML:

```
<list>
  <item id="red" type="colors"/>
  <item id="green" type="colors"/>
  <item id="dog" type="pets"/>
  <item id="blue" type="pets"/> <!-- invalid because blue is not pets -->
  <item id="cat" type="pets"/>
</list>

<enumeration name="colors">
  <items>
     <item value="red"/>
     <item value="blue"/>
     <item value="green"/>
   <items>
</enumeration>

<enumeration name="pets">
  <items>
   <item value="dog"/>
   <item value="cat"/>
   <item value="chicken"/>
  </items>
</enumeration>
```

How can I write a constraint (XSD 1.0) to fail on the item marked invalid above? I'm stuck on how to create a reference and provide the specific collection's name (colors or pets) in that reference, based on the value of `type` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

Use **[Conditional Type Assignment](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative)** where `item` is typed according to its `@type` attribute.  This requires XSD 1.1.

**Example:** See *[How to make type depend on attribute value using Conditional Type Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27878402/290085)*

### Option 2

Redesign your XML such that the generic `item` name is replaced with a name that actually conveys the type of the element: `color` or `pet`:

```
<list>
  <color id="red"/>
  <color id="green"/>
  <pet id="dog"/>
  <pet id="blue"/>
  <pet id="cat"/>
</list>
```

Then, it is will be trivial to write an XSD for your XML, and you can do so in XSD 1.0.