# Extend XSD Type based on element value?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.1

Is it possible to extend an element in XSD 1.1 based on another element's value?

For example:

```
<Field>
    <Title>Text Field</Title>
    <Type>Text</Type>
    <Length>100</Length>
 </Field>

<Field>
    <Title>Date Field</Title>
    <Type>Date</Type>
    <Format>mm/dd/yyyy</Format>
<Field>
```

Both Field elements share common Title and Type elements.

For the Text Field, it can have a `Length` element, but Date cannot.

The Date `Field` can have `Format`, but `Text` cannot.

I'd like to extend both Text and Date fields, if possible, from a common type.

Note: I'm assuming the above is not possible in XSD 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, an element's type cannot depend upon the value of another element in XSD 1.0 or XSD 1.1.

### Alternative Solutions

1. Redesign your XML. Rather than have a generic `Field` element with a generic `Type`
   child element, include the type in the name of each element:

   ```
   <Text>
       <Title>Text Field</Title>
       <Length>100</Length>
   </Text>

   <Date>
       <Title>Date Field</Title>
       <Format>mm/dd/yyyy</Format>
   </Date>
   ```
2. Change `Type` from an element to an
   attribute and use XSD 1.1's **[Conditional Type Assignment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative)**.  For an example, see [How to make type depend on attribute value using Conditional Type Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878402/how-to-make-type-depend-on-attribute-value-using-conditional-type-assignment).  (XSD 1.1 only)
3. Express your constraints via `xs:assertion`.
   (XSD 1.1 only)

Alternative #1 is prefered and can be easily implemented in both XSD 1.0 or XSD 1.1.  It can also accommodate extension from a common base type.