# XML/XSD Troubleshooting

Tags: xml, xsd

> Hello,
>
> I have spent last 2 days working on a XSD specification and an example
>   of XML code that this XSD would validate. However, the XSD I have
>   created does not validate the XML and thus I have information from the
>   command line about the error, I was unable to identify the exact
>   cause.
>
> If anyone could help me with this, I would be thankful.
>
> The XML looks like this:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <peopleCatalogue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="zoznam-osoby.xsd">
> <person role="boss" typeOfContact="humanBeing">
>     <firstName>Anton</firstName>
>     <lastName>Mlaskal</lastName>
>     <email typeOfEmail="personal">mlaskalko.antonko@hotmail.com</email>
>     <email typeOfEmail="professional">mlaskal.anton@gmail.com</email>
>     <phoneNumber typeOfPhone="cell">+421 948 127 337</phoneNumber>
>     <phoneNumber typeOfPhone="home">+420 2 48 48 48</phoneNumber>
>     <web>www.mlaskal.com</web>
>     <adress>
>       <streetName>Lubovnikova</streetName>
>       <houseNumber>7</houseNumber>
>       <postalCode>84107</postalCode>
>       <cityName>Bratislava</cityName>
>       <country>Slovakia</country>
>     </adress>
>     <note typeOfNote="action">Please, kill him as soon as possible.</note>
>     <note typeOfNote="undercoverInformation">He is the boss of the whole drug cartel we need to eradicate.</note>
> </person>
>
> <person role="boss" typeOfContact="IDServicePair">
>     <service>Skype</service>
>     <ID>Antonius</ID>
> </person> </peopleCatalogue>
> ```
>
> The XSD looks like this:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
>
> <xsd:element name="peopleCatalogue">
>     <xsd:complexType>
>         <xsd:all>
>             <xsd:element name="person">
>                 <xsd:complexType>    
>                     <xsd:attribute name="role" type="xsd:string" default="unknown"/>
>                     <xsd:attribute name="typeOfContact">
>                         <xsd:simpleType>
>                             <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
>                                 <xsd:pattern value="humanBeing|IDServicePair"/>
>                             </xsd:restriction>
>                         </xsd:simpleType>
>                     </xsd:attribute>
>                 </xsd:complexType>
>             </xsd:element>
>         </xsd:all>
>     </xsd:complexType>    
> </xsd:element>
>
> <xsd:complexType name="IDServicePair">
>     <xsd:all> 
>         <xsd:element name="ID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
>             <xsd:simpleType>
>                 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
>                     <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z0-9 ])*"/>
>                 </xsd:restriction>
>             </xsd:simpleType>
>         </xsd:element>
>         <xsd:element name="service" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
>             <xsd:simpleType>
>                 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
>                     <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z0-9 ~!@#$%^*])*"/>
>                 </xsd:restriction>
>             </xsd:simpleType>
>         </xsd:element>
>     </xsd:all> 
> </xsd:complexType>
>
>
> <xsd:element name="humanBeing">
>     <xsd:complexType>
>         <xsd:all>
>             <xsd:element name="firstName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
>                 <xsd:simpleType>
>                     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
>                         <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z])*"/>
>                     </xsd:restriction>
>                 </xsd:simpleType>
>             </xsd:element>
>
>             <xsd:element name="lastName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
>                 <xsd:simpleType>
>                     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
>                         <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z])*"/>
>                     </xsd:restriction>
>                 </xsd:simpleType>
>             </xsd:element>
>
>             <xsd:element name="email">
>                 <xsd:complexType>
>                     <xsd:simpleContent>
>                         <xsd:extension base="emailPattern">  
>                             <xsd:attribute name="typeOfEmail" default="personal"/>
>                         </xsd:extension>
>                     </xsd:simpleContent>
>                 </xsd:complexType>
>             </xsd:element>
>
>             <xsd:element name="phoneNumber">
>                 <xsd:complexType>
>                     <xsd:simpleContent>
>                         <xsd:extension base="phonePattern">  
>                             <xsd:attribute name="typeOfPhone" default="cell"/>
>                         </xsd:extension>
>                     </xsd:simpleContent>
>                 </xsd:complexType>
>             </xsd:element>
>
>             <xsd:element name="web">
>                 <xsd:simpleType>
>                     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
>                         <xsd:pattern value="(https?://[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,9})|(www(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+((\.[a-zA-Z]{2,9}){1}))"/>
>                     </xsd:restriction>
>                 </xsd:simpleType>
>             </xsd:element>
>
>             <xsd:element name="adress">
>                 <xsd:complexType>
>                     <xsd:all>
>
>                         <xsd:element name="streetName">
>                             <xsd:simpleType>
>                                 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
>                                     <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z ])*"/>
>                                 </xsd:restriction>
>                             </xsd:simpleType>    
>                         </xsd:element>
>
>                         <xsd:element name="houseNumber">
>                             <xsd:simpleType>
>                                 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
>                                     <xsd:pattern value="([0-9])*"/>
>                                     <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
>                                     <xsd:maxInclusive value="99999"/>
>                                 </xsd:restriction>
>                             </xsd:simpleType>    
>                         </xsd:element>
>
>                         <xsd:element name="postalCode">
>                             <xsd:simpleType>
>                                 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
>                                     <xsd:pattern value="([0-9])*"/>
>                                     <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
>                                     <xsd:maxInclusive value="99999"/>
>                                 </xsd:restriction>
>                             </xsd:simpleType>
>                         </xsd:element>
>
>                         <xsd:element name="cityName">
>                             <xsd:simpleType>
>                                 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
>                                     <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z ])*"/>
>                                 </xsd:restriction>
>                             </xsd:simpleType>
>                         </xsd:element>
>
>                         <xsd:element name="country">
>                             <xsd:simpleType>
>                                 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
>                                     <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z ])*"/>
>                                 </xsd:restriction>
>                             </xsd:simpleType>
>                         </xsd:element>
>                     </xsd:all>
>                 </xsd:complexType>    
>             </xsd:element>
>
>             <xsd:element name="note">
>                 <xsd:complexType>  
>                     <xsd:simpleContent>  
>                         <xsd:extension base="noteType">  
>                             <xsd:attribute name="typeOfNote"/>  
>                         </xsd:extension>  
>                     </xsd:simpleContent>  
>                 </xsd:complexType>  
>             </xsd:element>    
>         </xsd:all>
> </xsd:complexType> </xsd:element>
> ```
>
> The error message I get, when I try to validate the xml file with xsd
>   through
>
> ```
> xmllint --noout --schema zoznam-osoby.xsd OnePerson.xml in command line is this:
>
> OnePerson.xml:3: element person: Schemas validity error : Element 'person': Character content is not allowed, because the content type
> is empty.
> OnePerson.xml:3: element person: Schemas validity error : Element 'person': Element content is not allowed, because the content type is
> empty.
> OnePerson.xml:22: element person: Schemas validity error : Element 'person': This element is not expected.
> OnePerson.xml fails to validate
> ```
>
> It tells me, that the content type is empty, but I have no idea, what
>   kind of content this is about. What to do to make it functional?

Comment: Your schema and your question showcase considerable gaps in your understanding of XML Schema. I suggest that you first study relevant learning material, for example [Definitive XML Schema](http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/), or the W3C [XML Schema Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/).

Comment: Could you please briefly elaborate this?

Comment: Well, the error message already tells you everything you need to know. In the schema, `person` is declared as an element with empty content, which means that it cannot contain other elements.

Comment: I am looking for the line where I have declared it as an element with empty content, but I cannot find the answer. That is the reason why I am asking anyone willing to point me in the right direction.

Comment: As I said, you should study relevant learning material. Then you would know that an element with empty content simply is declared [by not including any content in its declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#emptyContent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for type definition problems (fixed in the examples below), you are generally looking for Conditional Type Assignment defined starting with version 1.1 of the XML Schema standard (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27880329.

XML Schema v1.1 data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<peopleCatalogue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="zoznam-osoby.xsd">
    <person role="boss" typeOfContact="humanBeing">
        <firstName>Anton</firstName>
        <lastName>Mlaskal</lastName>
        <email typeOfEmail="personal">mlaskalko.antonko@hotmail.com</email>
        <email typeOfEmail="professional">mlaskal.anton@gmail.com</email>
        <phoneNumber typeOfPhone="cell">+421 948 127 337</phoneNumber>
        <phoneNumber typeOfPhone="home">+420 2 48 48 48</phoneNumber>
        <web>www.mlaskal.com</web>
        <adress>
            <streetName>Lubovnikova</streetName>
            <houseNumber>7</houseNumber>
            <postalCode>84107</postalCode>
            <cityName>Bratislava</cityName>
            <country>Slovakia</country>
        </adress>
        <note typeOfNote="action">Please, kill him as soon as possible.</note>
        <note typeOfNote="undercoverInformation">He is the boss of the whole drug cartel we need to eradicate.</note>
    </person>

    <person role="boss" typeOfContact="IDServicePair">
        <service>Skype</service>
        <ID>Antonius</ID>
    </person> 
</peopleCatalogue>
```

XML Schema v1.1 definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
            vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xsd:element name="peopleCatalogue">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="person" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:alternative test="@typeOfContact = humanBeing" type="humanBeing"/>        
                    <xsd:alternative test="@typeOfContact = IDServicePair" type="IDServicePair"/>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="IDServicePair">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="ID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z0-9 ])*"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="service" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z0-9 ~!@#$%^*])*"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:all>
        <xsd:attribute name="role" type="xsd:string" default="unknown"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="typeOfContact" type="xsd:string" fixed="IDServicePair"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="humanBeing">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="firstName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z])*"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="lastName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z])*"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="email" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:simpleContent>
                        <xsd:extension base="emailPattern">  
                            <xsd:attribute name="typeOfEmail" default="personal"/>
                        </xsd:extension>
                    </xsd:simpleContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="phoneNumber" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:simpleContent>
                        <xsd:extension base="phonePattern">  
                            <xsd:attribute name="typeOfPhone" default="cell"/>
                        </xsd:extension>
                    </xsd:simpleContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="web">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:pattern value="(https?://[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,9})|(www(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+((\.[a-zA-Z]{2,9}){1}))"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="adress">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:all>

                        <xsd:element name="streetName">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z ])*"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>    
                        </xsd:element>

                        <xsd:element name="houseNumber">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                                    <xsd:pattern value="([0-9])*"/>
                                    <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                    <xsd:maxInclusive value="99999"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>    
                        </xsd:element>

                        <xsd:element name="postalCode">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                                    <xsd:pattern value="([0-9])*"/>
                                    <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                    <xsd:maxInclusive value="99999"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>

                        <xsd:element name="cityName">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z ])*"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>

                        <xsd:element name="country">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z ])*"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:all>
                </xsd:complexType>    
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="note" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>  
                    <xsd:simpleContent>  
                        <xsd:extension base="noteType">  
                            <xsd:attribute name="typeOfNote"/>  
                        </xsd:extension>  
                    </xsd:simpleContent>  
                </xsd:complexType>  
            </xsd:element>    
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="role" type="xsd:string" default="unknown"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="typeOfContact" type="xsd:string" fixed="humanBeing"/>

    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="emailPattern">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value=".+@.+"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="phonePattern">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="\+[\d\s]+"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="noteType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

However, I am not sure how widespread support of v1.1 of XML Schema is (at least NetBeans 8.2 failed to understand it). So I suggest to use XML Schema v1.0 definition distinguishing element type by the element name itself rather then by the value of an required attribute. I do not see much sense in doing so – why to use the same element name when the required attribute totally changes its allowed contents?

XML Schema v1.0 data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<peopleCatalogue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="zoznam-osoby.xsd">
    <humanBeing role="boss">
        <firstName>Anton</firstName>
        <lastName>Mlaskal</lastName>
        <email typeOfEmail="personal">mlaskalko.antonko@hotmail.com</email>
        <email typeOfEmail="professional">mlaskal.anton@gmail.com</email>
        <phoneNumber typeOfPhone="cell">+421 948 127 337</phoneNumber>
        <phoneNumber typeOfPhone="home">+420 2 48 48 48</phoneNumber>
        <web>www.mlaskal.com</web>
        <adress>
            <streetName>Lubovnikova</streetName>
            <houseNumber>7</houseNumber>
            <postalCode>84107</postalCode>
            <cityName>Bratislava</cityName>
            <country>Slovakia</country>
        </adress>
        <note typeOfNote="action">Please, kill him as soon as possible.</note>
        <note typeOfNote="undercoverInformation">He is the boss of the whole drug cartel we need to eradicate.</note>
    </humanBeing>

    <IDServicePair role="boss">
        <service>Skype</service>
        <ID>Antonius</ID>
    </IDServicePair> 
</peopleCatalogue>
```

XML Schema v1.0 definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="peopleCatalogue">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element name="humanBeing" type="humanBeing"/>
                <xsd:element name="IDServicePair" type="IDServicePair"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="IDServicePair">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="ID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z0-9 ])*"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="service" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z0-9 ~!@#$%^*])*"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:all>
        <xsd:attribute name="role" type="xsd:string" default="unknown"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="humanBeing">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="firstName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z])*"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="lastName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z])*"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="email" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:simpleContent>
                        <xsd:extension base="emailPattern">  
                            <xsd:attribute name="typeOfEmail" default="personal"/>
                        </xsd:extension>
                    </xsd:simpleContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="phoneNumber" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:simpleContent>
                        <xsd:extension base="phonePattern">  
                            <xsd:attribute name="typeOfPhone" default="cell"/>
                        </xsd:extension>
                    </xsd:simpleContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="web">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:pattern value="(https?://[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,9})|(www(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+((\.[a-zA-Z]{2,9}){1}))"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="adress">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:all>

                        <xsd:element name="streetName">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z ])*"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>    
                        </xsd:element>

                        <xsd:element name="houseNumber">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                                    <xsd:pattern value="([0-9])*"/>
                                    <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                    <xsd:maxInclusive value="99999"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>    
                        </xsd:element>

                        <xsd:element name="postalCode">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                                    <xsd:pattern value="([0-9])*"/>
                                    <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                    <xsd:maxInclusive value="99999"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>

                        <xsd:element name="cityName">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z ])*"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>

                        <xsd:element name="country">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:pattern value="([a-zA-Z ])*"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:all>
                </xsd:complexType>    
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="note" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>  
                    <xsd:simpleContent>  
                        <xsd:extension base="noteType">  
                            <xsd:attribute name="typeOfNote"/>  
                        </xsd:extension>  
                    </xsd:simpleContent>  
                </xsd:complexType>  
            </xsd:element>    
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="role" type="xsd:string" default="unknown"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="emailPattern">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value=".+@.+"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="phonePattern">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="\+[\d\s]+"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="noteType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of effort, I solved it.

Basically, what I tried to do, was to specify some kind of an IF statement inside an XML schema. If a person has a typeOfContact = humanBeing, I wanted it to have a set of elements, if it is of typeOfContact = IDServicePair, I wanted it to have just two elements (ID + service).

I thought that if I specify the attribute as a complexType, this would be possible. However, it is not and after hours of effort, you will end up with the same error I have ended up with, with people seemingly answering, but basically just talking to you like a child.

So I just deleted a lot of my work and just dealt with the fact, that I cannot do that.