# How to create conditional tags in xsd 1.0?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to create an xml schema for this kind of xml file:

```
<root>

    <class type="A">
        <name>My Name</name>
        <surname>My Surname</surname>
        <address-eu>
            <postalcode>555888</postalcode>
        </address-eu>
    </class>
    <class type="B">
        <name>My Name</name>
        <surname>My Surname</surname>
        <address-us>
            <zipcode>555888</zipcode>
        </address-us>
    </class>

<root>
```

What I want, is to add **address-eu** or **address-us** depending on the value of type in tag class.

Using XSD 1.1 is easy but I need to implement it using xsd 1.0.

I want to avoid a xml file like this, where address-us is in a class of type="A", which is not correct:

```
<root>

    <class type="A">
        <name>My Name</name>
        <surname>My Surname</surname>
        <address-us>
            <zipcode>555888</zipcode>
        </address-us>
    </class>
    <class type="B">
        <name>My Name</name>
        <surname>My Surname</surname>
        <address-us>
            <zipcode>555888</zipcode>
        </address-us>
    </class>

<root>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: **You really ought to accept some of the fine answers you've received to the [23 questions you've asked](http://stackoverflow.com/users/678824/davisoski?tab=questions&sort=newest).**   If you've only truly been helped once for the 23 questions you've asked, please read [ask] and seriously improve the way you ask questions.  If you've been helped more than once, it's not too late to go back and upvote and accept helpful answers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you cannot have an element type be based on an attribute value in XSD 1.0.

In XSD 1.1, you can use **[Conditional Type Assignment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative)**.  For an example of CTA, see [How to make type depend on attribute value using Conditional Type Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878402/how-to-make-type-depend-on-attribute-value-using-conditional-type-assignment)

In XSD 1.0, you can rename element `class` with `type="A"` to `A` or `ClassA` to distinguish it from elements named `B` or `ClassB`.  Then you'll be able to define distinct content models for the two elements.

**In general, in XSD 1.0, different elements should have different names.**

Comment: So for this classs with two types I should Have two classes, lets say: class-type-a and class-type-b??

Comment: Yes, if you want two elements in XSD 1.0 to have different types, you have to name them differently.