# Element values available in XSD based on the value of another element

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Given the following XML:

```
<category>1000</category>
<type>a</type>
```

And this XSD for validation:

```
<xs:element name="category" type="categoryType"/>
<xs:element name="type" type="xs:string">

<xs:simpleType name="categoryType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="1000"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="1010"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="1020"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="1030"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="1040"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

How can I check the type value if:

- type = a (avaliable in category: all)
- type = b (avaliable in category: 1000,1020,1030)
- type = c (avaliable in category: 1000,1010,1030,1040)
- type = d (avaliable in category: 1000,1010,1020,1030)

Answer (score 0):

### XSD 1.0

Not possible without redesigning your XML such that type differentiation is conveyed via element name rather than a `@type` attribute.

### XSD 2.0

Define new types via restrictions on `categoryType` for each of `b, c, d`, then use [Conditional Type Assignment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative) to allow type to vary per `@type`.

See also: [How to make type depend on attribute value using Conditional Type Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27878402/290085)

Comment: In this case `type` is a child element rather than an attribute, so conditional type assignment won't work; it has to be done using assertions.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Oh, OP does indeed show it as an element.  I suppose, short of XML redesign, that leaves `xs:assert` or out-of-band wrt XSD checking of the constraint.  Thanks.